# Time for which a drop stays in the leidenfrost point

Tags: thermodynamics, water, evaporation

Is there any way to find out the time required for a drop of given dimensions to vaporize after attaining [Leidenfrost point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leidenfrost_effect)?

Answer (score -1):

Yes & No. Basically it's just straight forward calculations. But as even such a factors like the dropping height influences greatly to the time, it is as meaningful as calculating the result of coin flipping.

The main loss of water is happening through the steam loss under the droplet. Thus even the microscopical differences can influence a lot to the droplet behaviour (movement) and this is even temperature dependent.

To understand the detail levels pls look this video;

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzKgnNGqxMw

Look atleast 2:30 forward.